# Why does my new form keep moving to the back?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Visual Basic .NET using Visual Studio 2013

I have a form that I open from another form, but when I do, it always goes behind the form that opened it. Al code that passes to the new form, gets passed before the form.Show().

Here is the code that opens the new form.

```
Private Sub OpenContentWindow(strNewNavigation As String)

    Dim newContent As New FContent

    newContent.SetIETMPath(strIETMPath)
    newContent.SetIETMName(strIETMName)
    newContent.SetIETMMan(strNewNavigation)
    newContent.SetIETMIcon(strIETMIcon)
    newContent.SetPageToLaunch(strNewNavigation)
    newContent.Show()

End Sub
```

Here is the code from the new form.

```
Public Class FContent



#Region "Variables/Class Instances"

Private logger As New CDataLogger
Private pathing As New CPaths
Private annotes As New CAnnotes
Private mouser As New CMouse
Private strIETMPath As String
Private strIETMName As String
Private strIETMMan As String
Private strIETMIcon As String
Private strPageToLaunch As String

#End Region



#Region "Load Sub Routines"

' Form Load
Private Sub FContent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Text = strIETMName
    Me.Icon = New System.Drawing.Icon(strIETMIcon)
    StartNavigation(strPageToLaunch)

End Sub

' Just pass in the file you want to view
Public Sub StartNavigation(strFileToNavigate As String)

    StartNavigation(strFileToNavigate, True)

End Sub

' Just pass in the file you want to view ( if a manual change it will load TOCs also )
Public Sub StartNavigation(strFileToNavigate As String, blnManual As Boolean)

    If blnManual Then
        wbContent.Navigate(New Uri(strIETMPath & strFileToNavigate))
        wbTOC.Navigate(New Uri(strIETMPath & strIETMMan & "\toc.html"))
        wbLOF.Navigate(New Uri(strIETMPath & strIETMMan & "\lof.html"))
        wbLOT.Navigate(New Uri(strIETMPath & strIETMMan & "\lot.html"))
        wbLOC.Navigate(New Uri(strIETMPath & strIETMMan & "\loc.html"))
    Else
        wbContent.Navigate(New Uri(strIETMPath & strFileToNavigate))
    End If

End Sub

#End Region



#Region "Set Sub Routines"

' Set IETM Path
Public Sub SetIETMPath(strNewIETM As String)

    strIETMPath = strNewIETM

End Sub

' Set IETM Name
Public Sub SetIETMName(strNewIETM As String)

    strIETMName = strNewIETM

End Sub

' Set IETM Manual
Public Sub SetIETMMan(strNewIETM As String)

    strIETMMan = strNewIETM.Substring(0, strNewIETM.IndexOf("/"))

End Sub

' Set IETM Icon
Public Sub SetIETMIcon(strNewIETM As String)

    strIETMIcon = strNewIETM

End Sub

' Set Page To Launch
Public Sub SetPageToLaunch(strNewPage As String)

    strPageToLaunch = strNewPage

End Sub

#End Region
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to ensure the display above the calling form is to set the [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the called form to the instance of the calling form.

So, supposing that this `OpenContentWindow` method is inside the class code of the form that want to create the instance of an `FContent` you could call the [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx) method passing the reference to the current form instance

```
Private Sub OpenContentWindow(strNewNavigation As String)

    Dim newContent As New FContent

    newContent.SetIETMPath(strIETMPath)
    newContent.SetIETMName(strIETMName)
    newContent.SetIETMMan(strNewNavigation)
    newContent.SetIETMIcon(strIETMIcon)
    newContent.SetPageToLaunch(strNewNavigation)
    newContent.Show(Me)

End Sub
```

In the link above (MSDN) you could read

> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the
>   owner form. For example, consider a form named Form2 that is owned by
>   a form named Form1. If Form1 is closed or minimized, Form2 is also
>   closed or hidden. **Owned forms are also never displayed behind their
>   owner form.** You can use owned forms for windows such as find and
>   replace windows, which should not disappear when the owner form is
>   selected. To determine the forms that are owned by a parent form, use
>   the OwnedForms property.

Comment: Ok that works and makes total sense, thank you.  I do have one question now though, how come the parent form doesn't go behind its parent when opened?

Comment: Ran into another issue.  The user will need to be able to open multiple new windows from the parent, and setting the owner in the show method prevents me from going back to the parent without closing or minimizing the child window.

Comment: Well, now that seems a work for MDI Forms. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C or this old tutorial in VB.NET http://www.authorcode.com/mdi-form-in-vb-net/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help.  Just to experiment, I created a blank form with no data going to it or code in it.  When I do Form1.Show() from a menustrip or button, the new form opens on top.  But if I open it from the TreeView, it goes behind the previous window.  Is there something different about the TreeView?

Comment: Uhm, can't help with that control. Always avoided, perhaps you should post a new question and get new attention to your question.

Comment: Ok I'll try that.  But what you suggested did work for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try "newContent.BringToFront()" after newContent.Show () or newContent.TopMost =true ?

Comment: Did that on the previous program I was working on.  Figured I would try to figure out why I had the problem first.  But I was able to set the owner in the Show() method, and that fixes it.