# Why does my new form move behind the opener?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm not going to post a bunch of code here since I do not think it is a code issue. 
Here is a link to my original question where I have shown the code if you are interested. [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058761/why-does-my-new-form-keep-moving-to-the-back/26058879?noredirect=1#comment40825975_26058879)

Just as a test I created a blank form window (Form1.vb) and no code gets passed to it and no code runs when it opens.  If I do Form1.Show() from a MenuStrip Control or a Button Control, the window opens and stays on top.  Now if I do Form1.Show() from a TreeView Control, the window opens and goes behind the window with the TreeView Control.

So my question is, what is different about the TreeView opening a form vs a button or other control?

I am using the basic VB TreeView Controll, and the new form is being called in AfterSelect method for the TreeView.

Comment: What *event* in the control are you responding to by attempting `Form1.Show()`?

Comment: I am using the basic VB TreeView Controll, and the new form is being called in AfterSelect method for the TreeView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AfterSelect works if you use your keyboard navigation to select a node, but it doesn't work when you use the mouse because the mouse capture is forcing the parent form to remain in focus.  You would have to run your code *after* the AfterSelect event:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) _
                                  Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
  Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                              Dim f2 As New Form2
                              f2.Show(Me)
                            End Sub))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Form.Show(parentForm) option, this will always put the new form on top of the old one.

Comment: It says so in the link the OP posted

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Form1.ShowDialog() ? or if you don't want to show it as a dialog you should use:

```
Form1.Show()
Form1.BringToFront()
```